# What does 'stack limit exceeded' mean?

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are building a tool to off-board existing employees, including clearing their calendars of all existing events. When querying the /calendars/{calendarID}/events/ endpoint, we are occasionally getting a `500 - Stack limit exceeded` error. We're only generating a few dozen to hundred requests, so we don't seem to be hitting any rate limits, which appear to be 10k per day; additionally, it's only intermittent, rather than a failing continuously, as a rate limit would generally cause. Anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: Can you share the code you use to run this? Stack limit exceeded indicates there's a memory issue, the limit likely doesn't come from your daily limits but from an individual execution. How many requests are you making and how are you making them?

Comment: Hi @RafaGuillermo - I can't share the exact code, because we're using an automation platform - Okta's Workflows product. That said, it's just making basic `GET` calls to the `/calendars/{calendarID}/events/` endpoint. We set the flow to run recursively, paginating through results; at first we left the default `maxResults` so it was running a few dozen times per execution. We upped it to 2500 and haven't had the error repeat, but I'd rather not assume it won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the Calendar API related errors by checking this link [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors).

As for the error message `500 - Stack limit exceeded` you are receiving, it looks like the issue might in fact be coming from somewhere else.

You can also test the Calendar API by using the Calendar API Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get).

#### Reference

- [Calendar API Errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors);
- [Calendar API Events:get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get).